# How to clean up after Android Studio unistallation on Linux?

Tags: linux, android-studio, uninstallation, reinstall

I use Android Studio on Linux. I need to make a clean start with Android Studio so I tried to uninstall it. I wonder what I am missing to delete.

When I uninstall Android Studio (Giraffe) I:

- remove android-studio directory (the program)
- remove ~/.android
- remove ~/.gradle
- remove ~/.cache/Google

When I then install a new version of Android Studio:

1. It still starts with the last project and the latest project list is still there.
2. A device that isn't in the Device Manager list, I have deleted it (located in .android/avd), still pops up in Running Devices.

I have also tried File -> Invalidate Caches.

What am I missing to delete?

Comment: No idea - but you should be able to get a list of files android studio touches when you launch it `strace -o debug.log -e openat  <program>` and then looking at the generated log ...

Comment: Thank you @tink for your suggestion! I tested `-o debug.log -e openat ./studio.sh` as you wrote and a bit around after checking the specification a bit. I tried starting Android studio with strace. I tried running the program I wrote with strace. I also deleted all files and directories as listed above again and reinstalling with strace. I did get result with android-studio directory, unfortunately, I never got a line that contained ./android or ./gradle and I know these are created/changed. I didn't get any other noticeable results. So the mystery remains.

Comment: You may need to retest with a `-f` flag added - I didn't know that android studio is started with a shell script.